# Ruby Rails--easy way to get animated front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, visualization, graphviz

I am developing a web-based simulation where I want the front-end to be "animated" in real-time--it will be a mapping application, and I want to have little icons (representing the components of my simulation) moving all over the map as the simulation runs. I am developing the back-end in Rails, but I am wondering what are good packages to use for the front-end / animation part? I used Graphviz to generate the base map (a directed graph), but it doesn't seem well suited for live animations.

Something like Hans Rosling's Gapminder (if it's even possible to do in real-time). Or should I be doing something similar and "recording" the data then playing it back? What packages should I consider in that case?
[Gapminder](http://www.gapminder.org/world/#%24majorMode=chart%24is;shi=t;ly=2003;lb=f;il=t;fs=11;al=30;stl=t;st=t;nsl=t;se=t%24wst;tts=C%24ts;sp=5.59290322580644;ti=2011%24zpv;v=1%24inc_x;mmid=XCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj1jiMAkmq1iMg;by=ind%24inc_y;mmid=YCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA;by=ind%24inc_s;uniValue=8.21;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ;by=ind%24inc_c;uniValue=255;gid=CATID0;by=grp%24map_x;scale=log;dataMin=282;dataMax=119849%24map_y;scale=lin;dataMin=12;dataMax=83%24map_s;sma=49;smi=2.65%24cd;bd=0%24inds=;example=75)

Currently using Rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2, Graphviz 2.28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 javascript libraries that may help. You could use ajax calls to your rails backend to populate their data. I'm unsure if D3 has mapping capability, but I believe Raphael does. As far as real-time, you'll have to check out their documenation. In Rails 4, I believe the streaming capability may benefit you as well, but I've not investigated.

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

[D3](http://d3js.org/)

Comment: Thanks! These all look awesome--I will investigate more. Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to up vote...